# Pierce oscillator issues

Tags: oscillator

I am having a problem with Pierce oscillator designed to work with my SMART Card reader. I am using 3.58MHz oscillator, 74HCU04 gate IC for the NOT gate, and both 22pF capacitor and 1Mohm resistor. I was unable to get any clock pulse.

Comment: Measure the voltage with a multimeter from output of NOT gate to ground - it should be around one-half Vdd (+5v) - that's WITH the 1Mohm resistor from output to input. Also, add a 0.1uf capacitor from 74HCU04 Vdd (pin 14) to gnd (pin 7).

Answer (score 1):

The Pierce oscillator requires two capacitors! See [this circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierce_oscillator).

The capacitor values depend on the crystal load capacitance; they are effectively in series so you need roughly twice the value of the load capacitance. You need to allow for stray capacitance.

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried it with the 2 capacitors, but still didn't get anything. How can i get the crystal load capacitance?

Comment: It'll be in the crystal specification. It should work with two 22pF capacitors, although the frequency might be slightly out. Check your soldering.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing one capacitor? Also, you should separate the oscillator from other circuits by another inverter, otherwise you may be overloading it.

Comment: Thanks. I actually used two capacitors in my schematic, and also another inverter at the output, but still that dint work!